# Searching nested JSON object's via SQL within Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I have this JSON file within the Items in a Cosmos DB Container hosted in Azure.

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "category": "apps",
    "apps": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "category": "apps",
            "name": "testApp",
            "description": "I'm a test app!",
            "developer": "test developer",
            "created_at": "6/9/2021",
            "updated_at": "6/9/2021"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "category": "apps",
            "name": "testAPp2",
            "description": "I'm a test app 2!",
            "developer": "test developer2",
            "created_at": "6/9/2021",
            "updated_at": "6/9/2021"
        }
    ]
}
```

I have been trying to access one of the apps whose name matches my parameter as such:

```
SELECT *
FROM Items c
WHERE c.category = 'apps'
AND WHERE c.apps.name = 'testApp'
```

I am able to access the apps with the query

```
SELECT c.apps
FROM Items c
WHERE c.category = 'apps'
```

But I am unable to figure out how to access one of the individual apps hosted within the apps array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have been trying to access one of the apps whose name matches my
> parameter

You can try to use this SQL:

```
SELECT value a
FROM Items c
JOIN a in c.apps
WHERE c.category = 'apps' and a.name = 'testApp'
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "category": "apps",
        "name": "testApp",
        "description": "I'm a test app!",
        "developer": "test developer",
        "created_at": "6/9/2021",
        "updated_at": "6/9/2021"
    }
]
```

BTW, if you want to access the particular item in your apps array, you can use c.apps[index] to get it. Such as

```
SELECT value c.apps[1] 
FROM c
where c.category = 'apps'
```

Result:

```
[
    {
        "id": "2",
        "category": "apps",
        "name": "testAPp2",
        "description": "I'm a test app 2!",
        "developer": "test developer2",
        "created_at": "6/9/2021",
        "updated_at": "6/9/2021"
    }
]
```